# why do i get unicode error from python code

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I just want to print the browser title

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\akika\Drivers\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
```

however I get this error message:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"
```

Can anyone point out my error in the code pls?

Comment: Please post your code, your input, and your expected output.

Comment: When asking about Python it's always important to specify which Python version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

`\` are escape characters in Python, one solution will be using raw string `r`

```
executable_path = r"C:\Users\akika\Drivers\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
```

or escape the escape character using `\\`

```
executable_path = "C:\\Users\\akika\\Drivers\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"
```